# Include not available in covering indexes in SQL Server 2008 Express

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, indexing, ssms

In MS SQL Server Manager Studio for 2008 Express, the "Included Columns" field is always grayed out in the "Indexes/Keys" window in the Database Diagram designer.

Per the help, this should be available so long as I'm not creating a clustered index.

Further, if I run a query to create the index (which runs fine), the created query doesn't list for the table it was added against.

I don't see anywhere where MS says this feature is unavailable in the Express version.

Any ideas?

**Further data:**

This is the script that creates the table:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IX_SocialTypes_Cover ON ClientSocialTypes(ClientID, SocialTypeID, [Source]) INCLUDE (URLID)
```

Here is the table gen script (the index is missing):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ClientSocialTypes](
    [SocialTypeID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ClientID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SocialTypeClassID] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [Source] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [TagCount] [int] NOT NULL,
    [URLID] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ClientSources] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [SocialTypeID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]    
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ClientSocialTypes]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_ClientSocialTypes_Clients] FOREIGN KEY([ClientID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID])
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ClientSocialTypes] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_ClientSocialTypes_Clients]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ClientSocialTypes]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_ClientSocialTypes_SocialTypeClasses] FOREIGN KEY([SocialTypeClassID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[SocialTypeClasses] ([SocialTypeClassID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ClientSocialTypes] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_ClientSocialTypes_SocialTypeClasses]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ClientSocialTypes] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_ClientSocialTypes_SocialTypeClassID]  DEFAULT ((1)) FOR [SocialTypeClassID]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ClientSocialTypes] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_ClientSocialTypes_TagCount]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [TagCount]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ClientSocialTypes] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_ClientSocialTypes_HasTrackedURL]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [URLID]
GO
```

Comment: generate the full table script and see what it says please.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turns out this is grayed out in the full version of SQL Server too. In SSMS, use the Object Explorer (not the Designer) to navigate to {database_name} > Tables > {table_name} > Indexes to manage indexes that have includes.

Answer (score 11):

There's TWO different index dialogs. An ancient horrible awful one, and a new (only just discovered it) one that actually lets you change these things.

**OLD HORRIBLE ONE**

- Right click on a table in your main tables list
- Click 'Design'
- Right click on the list of columns and select 'Indexes/Keys'

This doesn't let you change included columns.

**NEW NICE ONE**

- Expand the table in your main tables list to show the 'Columns', 'Keys', 'Constraints', 'Triggers' etc folders
- Expand the `Indexes` folder
- Right click `Indexes` folder for `New Index`
- Right click existing index and click `Properties` to edit an existing index

This newer dialog allows you to do a lot more and I'm kind of disappointed in Microsoft for keeping the old one alive and for  how long it's taken me to discover it.

Comment: Interestingly, the NEW NICE ONE is inaccessible to me for a newly created Table. ("Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 11.0.3153.0").  The `New Index` option is greyed out and the `Properties` context menu is also greyed out for existing.  Not sure why yet.

Comment: It is only grayed out if you have the 'design table' open for that table - you need to close the designer before you can open the 'new nice one'

Comment: Neither works with Azure SQL Database BTW  (exept for self hosted)

Answer (score 1):

The index may actually be a unique constraint (using CREATE/ALTER TABLE) rather than an index created using CREATE INDEX. Unique constraints don't allow INCLUDEs.

It's quite confusing... generate a script for the index/key entry or table and you'll be able to confirm.

Edit:

- When you create the index separately you have to refresh Object Explorer
- Do you have 2 SocialType tables in different schemas? (eg `dbo.SocialType` and `[domain\myuser].SocialType`). This can happen if you don't specify the schema in DDL statements.

Comment: I only have one such table, under the dbo schema. Really, question 1 is why won't the designer enable this field so I use it to create the index in the first place? The second question is why I can't see it with the designer after scripting it.

Comment: 1. Because it may not be an index 2. Refresh object explorer.